# I can't make a web service client in a GWT project with netbeans

Tags: web-services, gwt, netbeans

I have just made a GWT project with Netbeans (web application). The problem is that I can't make a web service client. In fact I always get the following error:

"No source code is available for type blablabla; did you forget to inherit a required module?"

I have dragged the methods of the web service client in the MainEntryPoint.java

Answer (score 0):

All classes uses in the client/shared packaged will be compiled to javascript code. Most likely the gwt compiler can't compile your webservice code.

You can move this code to a backend gwt service (async service, requestfactory, gwtp handler ...) and call this code from the gwt client / entrypoint.